# Can someone the differences between these two Express-React-Node application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm building an Express-React-Node app that I want to deploy on Google App Engine.

As I'm following several tutorials I've encountered these two apps architecture:

https://github.com/BalasubramaniM/react-nodejs-passport-app/tree/master/src

and

https://hackernoon.com/m-e-r-n-stack-application-using-passport-for-authentication-920b1140a134

I'd like to understand the differences.

The first one is only one app with Webpackand Babel.

On the client-side, I have a App.jsx file and Index.html file.

This is the App.jsx file:

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => (
    <div className='app'>This is a React app</div>
);

export default App;
```

And this is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Web App</title>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">This is an Express App</div>
    <script>
        ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(App.default),
            document.getElementById('app')
        );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The second one comes with a client app and a server app.

There is a index.jss file with the following code :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

and a App.js file with the following code:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import logo from "./logo.svg";
    import "./App.css";
    import queryString from "query-string";

    class App extends Component {
      componentWillMount() {
        var query = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
        if (query.token) {
          window.localStorage.setItem("jwt", query.token);
          this.props.history.push("/");
        }
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">

    //some stuff here

          </div>
        );
      }
    }
export default App;
```

There is nothing related to react in the html file.

I kind of understand that with the first project the rendering part is mixed within the html file but I'm not really able to understand the differences and does things articulate in one app and the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd one appears to be using the create-react-app engine to generate the scaffolding and starter files. The 2nd example incorporates JWT user authentication that gets stored in local storage whereas the first does not appear to do so. Additionally, the 2nd example leverages React Router which allows you to build a single-page web application with navigation without the page refreshing as the user navigates. React Router uses component structure to call components, which display the appropriate information and allows you to add routes rapidly to build out the navigation. That is how the App component is being rendered within the imported Route component prop in index.jss. And if someone adds another Route with another path containing another component prop like this:

```
<Route path="/another-path" component={SubComponent} />
```

you could then access that component by traveling to baseURL/another-path

Token authentication and the use of React-Router are the primary differences between these two projects.

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences. Both versions will call `ReactDOM.render` with an `App` element.

If you compile the second version using webpack, webpack will bundle all files together and will produce the same code as your first, partly manual solution.